# Ruby on Rails: error on concatenating string datatype field and boolean datatype field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concatenation, haml

I'm working on a Rails HAML View and I'm trying to display together two fields: the first one is String datatype and the other one is Boolean datatype, I'm trying with this line of code:

```
      %td=students.name + " " + students.status ? '(Passed)' : ''
```

As you can see I'm using a ternary operator to cast true to Passed and false to blank.

However, I'm getting this error:

[image: error_message]

Also, if I avoid ternary operator I got the same output error.

My question is: how can I cast these two fields and at the same time show "passed" if it is true?

Thanks a lot

Comment: To be clear, you are **not** trying to concatenate a string with a boolean (that's not valid in ruby). Your problem here is all about the order of operation, namely, trying to do multiple things in one line without brackets.

Comment: As a best practice, consider moving your strings into your locale file, rather than hard-coding English strings in your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```rb
%td=students.name + " " + (students.status ? '(Passed)' : '' )
```

Comment: thank you so much @LesNightingill it works as expected, all the best

Answer (score 1):

May be interpolation instead of concatenation?

And don't need ternary operator in that case because `nil.to_s == ""`

```
%td="#{students.name} #{'(Passed)' if students.status}"
```

or even just

```js
%td #{students[:name]} #{'(Passed)' if students[:status]}
```

Comment: If you're going to wrap the entire line in `"`, then drop the `"` and the `=`, they are redundant: `%td #{students[:name]} #{'(Passed)' if students[:status]}`